# Angular nested routes cannot load page by child path

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I have children in routes:

```
   RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: '', component: DashboardComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
      {
        path: 'app-main', component: AppMainComponent,
        children: [
          { path: '', redirectTo: 'guarantee', pathMatch: 'full' },
          { path: 'guarantee', component: GuaranteeComponent },
        ]
      },
      { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
      { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent }
```

My `app.component.html` looks like:

```
<div class="container">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

And my `app-main.component.html` looks like:

```
<div class="site d-flex">
  <div class="right-side">
    <div class="content d-flex flex-column">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I type in browser `localhost:4200` dashboard component is loaded correctly. In this component I have link to the quarantee:

```
  <li class="nav-item" [routerLinkActive]="['link-active']">
      <a [routerLink]="['guarantee']">Guarantee</a>
  </li>
```

When I click this link I get error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'guarantee'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'guarantee'
    at ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (router.js:4295)
    at CatchSubscriber.selector (router.js:4259)
    at CatchSubscriber.error (catchError.js:27)
    at MapSubscriber._error (Subscriber.js:75)
    at MapSubscriber.error (Subscriber.js:55)
    at MapSubscriber._error (Subscriber.js:75)
    at MapSubscriber.error (Subscriber.js:55)
    at MapSubscriber._error (Subscriber.js:75)
    at MapSubscriber.error (Subscriber.js:55)
    at ThrowIfEmptySubscriber._error (Subscriber.js:75)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:797)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:754)
    at zone-evergreen.js:858
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:391)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:39680)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:390)
    at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:168)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone-evergreen.js:559)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone-evergreen.js:469)
    at invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:1603)
defaultErrorLogger @ core.js:6014
handleError @ core.js:6066
next @ core.js:40558
schedulerFn @ core.js:35336
__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:183
next @ Subscriber.js:122
_next @ Subscriber.js:72
next @ Subscriber.js:49
next @ Subject.js:39
emit @ core.js:35298
(anonymous) @ core.js:39738
invoke @ zone-evergreen.js:359
run @ zone-evergreen.js:124
runOutsideAngular @ core.js:39572
onHandleError @ core.js:39735
handleError @ zone-evergreen.js:363
runGuarded @ zone-evergreen.js:137
api.microtaskDrainDone @ zone-evergreen.js:663
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone-evergreen.js:566
invokeTask @ zone-evergreen.js:469
invokeTask @ zone-evergreen.js:1603
globalZoneAwareCallback @ zone-evergreen.js:1629
```

I need to have website dashboard on full screen and the children components with menu. I read in the Internet that I have to use route children

---

I changed routerLink to this value:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/app-main/guarantee']">Guarantee</a>
```

and the same error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'app-main/guarantee'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'app-main/guarantee'
```

Comment: where your list item is there , it is in the different component or in the app-main.component??

Comment: What is mean list item ?

Comment: This one "<li class="nav-item" [routerLinkActive]="['link-active']">
      <a [routerLink]="['guarantee']">Guarantee</a>
  </li>"

Comment: This li is in the { path: '', component: DashboardComponent, pathMatch: 'full' }

Comment: then you need to use  <a [routerLink]="['/app-main/guarantee']">

Comment: @MskSatheesh: I added description in my question

Comment: can u reproduce this in stackblitz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try Using:**

```
<li class="nav-item" [routerLinkActive]="['link-active']">
    <a [routerLink]="['/', 'app-main']">Guarantee</a>
</li>
```

Here's the working **`stackblitz`**:

**https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-lhjpbv?file=src/app/dashboard/dashboard.component.html**

Comment: Yes, thanks, it works. could you tell me, it is right way to have some views with left and bottom menu and some views on full screen? Dashboard has to be on full screen, but other views have to have left and bottom menu and have to change in router-outlet in this view